# How can I find the original name of a renamed mapped network drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have renamed some mapped network drives in Windows 7 Explorer window to make them easier to identify. But how can I find out what the original names (i.e. the server name) were?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start > Computer > Map network drive > click on the drive letters, they will still show the full network path next to them